# How to avoid circular dependency with ip-address in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to set up elastic search and spark cluster using **cloud formation** 
I am using 2 ec2-instances one as master and the other as worker.

Worker is trying to get the master ip-address for spark cluster

Master is trying to get worker ip-address for elastic search cluster

Thereby causing an circular dependency error , how can i avoid it?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Solution: 
slaveip=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filter  Name=tag:Name,Values=bip-spark-es-worker3 |grep PrivateIpAddress |head -1|sed "s/[\"PrivateIpAddress:,\"]//g")

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can (in CFN).  I suggest you look at the AWS CLI to get one of your IP addresses instead of the FNGETATT.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim Bassett you made my day! 
I have posted my answer above if someone else faces this issue.